# Disable brightness and keyboard back-light at start-up?

Tags: keyboard, brightness, backlight

I'm new with Linux and I have an issue that I have being researching and have not been able to find a solution so far. I was wondering if any help can be given. I have an Asus Q500A with Win-8 and Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and Whenever i log-in to Ubuntu, it does so with full screen brightness and keyboard back-light at full . How do i get rid of this? How can I tweak the start-up setting for screen brightness and disable keyboard back-light at start-up?

Note: I already tried this and is not working.

Add this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo '2' > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: Did you get error after running above commands??

Comment: None at all, the computer start's up normally but the only problem is that boots with keyboard brightness and keyboard back-light again.

Answer (score 7):

To turn off the keyboard backlight on boot, you need to add this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/[a name related to your laptop ]/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

You have an Asus laptop but you input `applesmc.768` so it didn't work. For my case I added to `/etc/rc.local` the following line:

```
echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

and it worked.

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a ThinkPad X230.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad T450 and it worked but I added on `rc.local` before the line `sleep 3`

Answer (score 1):

3 years later I'm facing the same issue in Debian with Mate. I solved it this way:

1. Create a shellscript file in any path:

   ```
   sensible-editor login.sh
   ```
2. Add the following content to the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 3
   dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply=literal --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight.SetBrightness int32:0
   ```
3. Go to the Startup Applications

   [image]
4. Add a new item there that will call the full path to the file this way:

   ```
   sh /full/path/to/file/login.sh
   ```

Note in my case the `sleep 3` was essential. You need the `dbus-send` to run after the backlight keyboard turns on and it turned on a few seconds after Mate started. So the waiting was needed but how many seconds might depend on each system.

Also note this approach is better than the `/etc/rc.local` one because you don't need to run anything as root and you can still change the backlight intensity after it runs. After updating `/etc/rc.local` it was fixed in `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I first did the same thing you did but it didn't work for me neither.
you just need to add this to your `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo '0' > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

(that one worked for me)

If that doesn't work try with **xbacklight**

```
apt-get install xbacklight
```

after the install

```
xbacklight -set xx
```

where xx is a value you'll have to experiment with for your particular system.

For the keyboard I have no clue for now, because I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: `xbacklight` changes the screen backlight, not the keyboard backlight as the question asks about.